# How do I iterate a single argument in a gSheets statement rather than all of them?

Tags: function, google-sheets

google Sheets, Here's my function:

```
=IF(D2=C6,D3,"")
```

The problem is that all of the cells iterate when I try to autofill. How do I get this to work so that only the C column iterates and not the arguments that are from the D column?

I tried chatGPT and google and youtube

Comment: Sounds like you need to research absolute/relative cell references. How about `=IF(D2=$C6,D3,"")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your formula `D2` and `D3` are relative references that's why these references also iterate when you autofill.

Try to use this formula:

```
=IF($D$2=C6,$D$3,"")
```

The formula above will make `D2` and `D3` as absolute references for it to stay the same, and will only iterate `C` one row each when you autofill the formula.

### Reference:

- [Absolute and Relative references](https://www.w3schools.com/googlesheets/google_sheets_rel_ref.php)

Comment: If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)